# Excel web query append to table

Tags: excel-web-query

I have just worked out how to get data into a table using excel web query. However, every time the data is refreshed it overwrites the last update over the top. Can I use web query to load data into a table by appending to the existing table on each refresh instead of overwriting and losing the older data and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

Mike, I suggest making a sheet with your final data in it and copy your latest data into that sheet. So you have an update sheet that receives the new data and another sheet that stores the new data under the old data

```
`'Get onto the right sheet to copy daata
  Sheets("Data").Select
 'Start a loop
  Dim x As Integer
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  ' Set numrows = number of rows of data.
  NumRows = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
  ' Select cell a2.
  Range("A2").Select
  ' Establish "For" loop to loop "numrows" number of times.
  For x = 1 To NumRows

    Selection.copy
    'Get onto the right sheet
    Sheets("APIcall").Select

    'Activate the query for the specific data

    'delete the query so that it can be used again and unlist it to be able to manipulate it 
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries("query").Unlist       
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries("query").Delete

    'copy the info into the Data sheet into the next blank row
    Sheets("APIcall").Select
    Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.copy
    Sheets("Data").Select
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets("APIcall").Cells.Clear

'get the next data
Sheets("Data").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next`
```

This can most probably be done better and simpler, but hope it helps a bit.